# Unable to format Mac internal drive (disk0)

Tags: terminal, macos, disk-utility, disk-format

I have an macbook air late 2008 running osx El capitan and I wanted to erase my driver and reinstall the macos. So first i booted into recovery mode and tried formating my hard dive in disk utility but then I got an error
"MediaKit reports not enough space on device for requested operation" then again I tried the same thing for 3 times and it still showed me the same error. Then I tried formating the drive in terminal but I still get the same error. I tried searching the net and found solutions only for external drive and found no solution for a internal one. So pls tell me a solution to erase and reinstall the os in my mac.

**Note: I am trying to reinstall the OS on the primary internal disk that is disk0.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot from another disk and run disk utility and install from that drive.

You cannot boot from a disk that you want to erase or partition or re-install the system on.